# WCF works locally but not remotely

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm using a BasicHttpBinding with a service host of http://networkip:5678 and I'm just trying to host stand alone, I'm not using IIS...

```
let host = new ServiceHost(typeof<MyService>, [|new Uri("http://192.168.100.131:5678/")|])

let behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()

behavior.HttpGetEnabled <- true
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior)
let bind = new BasicHttpBinding()
bind.HostNameComparisonMode <- HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof<CQGService>, bind, "MyService") |> ignore
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof<IMetadataExchange>, bind, "MEX") |> ignore

host.Open()
```

It works great from the local machine but no one on the network can see it... I saw another post asking to run netstat so I did and I can see it listening on 0.0.0.0:5678. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double check make sure u don't have firewall blocking that port